# MySQL doesn't start in XAMPP (Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly...)

Tags: mysql

I've installed XAMPP on windows 10 but MySQL doesn't start. Why?

I have already tried with the task manager to see if another MySQL is running, but nothing. I tried to change the port but nothing. Please help.

image:

[image]

Here's the log:

```
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file \xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2019-04-27 11:53:56 12060 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? Did you follow its instructions?

Comment: This question has nithing to do with sw development, this is a pure admin issue. Therefore this question is off topuc here on SO.

Answer (score -1):

Delete `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` from your `MySQL` directory and try again. That should help.